# Get mac address of detected bluetooth devices

Tags: batch, console

How can I find out the mac address of all bluetooth devices the adapter has detected (not necessarily already paired with)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I find out the mac addresses of all bluetooth devices the adapter has detected?

Some possiblilites:

- [BluetoothCL](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetoothcl.html) (command line)
- [BluetoothView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetooth_viewer.html) (GUI)
- [BluetoothLogView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetooth_log_view.html) (GUI, with logging)

---

#### [BluetoothCL](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetoothcl.html) from [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/)

> BluetoothCL is a small console application that dumps all current detected bluetooth devices into the standard output. For each Bluetooth device, the following information is displayed: MAC Address, Name, Major Device Type, Minor Device Type, and optionally the company name of the device (if external file of MAC addresses - oui.txt is provided)

Example output:

```
F:\test>"c:\apps\WSCC\NirSoft Utilities\bluetoothcl"
BluetoothCL v1.07
Copyright (c) 2009 - 2014 Nir Sofer
Web Site: http://www.nirsoft.net

syntax:
BluetoothCL -timeout [seconds]

-timeout is optional parameter. The default value is 15 seconds.


Scanning bluetooth devices... please wait.

e4:90:7e:e3:fe:73    Phone           Smart           XT1068

F:\test>
```

Source [BluetoothCL](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetoothcl.html)

---

#### [BluetoothView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetooth_viewer.html) from [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/):

> BluetoothView is a small utility that runs in the background, and monitor the activity of Bluetooth devices around you. For each detected Bluetooth device, it displays the following information: Device Name, Bluetooth Address, Major Device Type, Minor Device Type, First Detection Time, Last Detection Time, and more.
>
> BluetoothView can also notify you when a new Bluetooth device is detected, by displaying a balloon in your taskbar or by playing a small beep sound.

Example output:

[image]

Source [BluetoothView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetooth_viewer.html)

#### [BluetoothLogView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetooth_log_view.html), also from [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/):

> BluetoothLogView is a small utility that monitors the activity of Bluetooth devices around you, and displays a log of Bluetooth devices on the main window.
>
> Every time that a new Bluetooth device arrives to your area and when the device leaves your area, a new log line is added with the following information: Device Name, Device Address, Event Time, Event Type ('Device Arrival' or 'Device Left'), Device Type, and the company that created the device.
>
> BluetoothLogView also allows you to specify a description for every device (according to its MAC address) that will appear under the 'Description' column.

Source [BluetoothLogView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetooth_log_view.html)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.