# Watching for Bluetooth Beacons has been disabled by the user - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I just bought an IBeacon and configured it, but I can't get my Windows 10 devices to listen/find them. My Android device does fine, so I know it's working, but I need Windows to be able to find it. I'm getting the following on both my computers (setup w/ Win 10 LTSC). Any ideas what settings I need to enable?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just using this beacon as a presence detector and was able to view it via NirSofts BluetoothCL.exe

[Get mac address of detected bluetooth devices](https://superuser.com/questions/1071723/get-mac-address-of-detected-bluetooth-devices)

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetoothcl.html

Now to just script the rest!

Comment: Did you have to use a dongle or could use the built-in bluetooth of Windows laptop, etc. to do the detection?

Comment: David, I used built in BT to detect Beacon using NirSoft